# How can I remove Firefox's List All Tabs button?

Tags: firefox, browser, tabs

Since Firefox 106, Firefox shows a "List all tabs" button in the tab bar no matter how many tabs you have open (even only one). You can move this button around the tab bar using the "Customize" feature, but you can't remove it. If you right-click on the button, then the "Remove from Toolbar" option is grayed out.

[This page](https://winaero.com/how-to-remove-firefox-view-and-list-all-tabs-from-firefox-toolbar/) and [this one](https://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-tabs-search-arrow-button-from-firefox-title-bar/) suggests going to about:config, setting "browser.tabs.tabmanager.enabled" to "false", and then restarting Firefox to remove the button. But this isn't working for me. I've set the option to "false" and it's still set to "false" after restarting my whole computer, but the "List all tabs" button is still stuck in the tab bar.

How can I make this button go away when I only have a few tabs open? I'm running Ubuntu 2.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide it using [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/).

The id is `#alltabs-button` so you can hide it via:

```
#alltabs-button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new tab, type `about:config` in the address bar, and hit `Enter`.
2. `Accept the risk and continue`
3. Set the `browser.tabs.tabmanager.enabled` to `false`
4. Restart the Firefox

Comment: The original question explicitly says that this method does not work.

Comment: @tparker Yeah I saw that, but it worked for me so I though it's better to have it here. It might help others as this question comes up in Google.